# How to read faster multiple CSV files using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

My program should read ~400.000 csv files and it takes very long. The code I use is:

```
        for file in self.files:
            size=2048
            csvData = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['acol', 'bcol'], header=None, skiprows=range(0,int(size/2)), skipfooter=(int(size/2)-10))

            for index in range(0,10):
                s=s+float(csvData['bcol'][index])
            s=s/10
            averages.append(s)
            time=file.rpartition('\\')[2]
            time=int(re.search(r'\d+', time).group())
            times.append(time)
```

Is there a chance to increase the speed?

Comment: You could use multithreading / subprocesses to fasten up things. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950893/processing-huge-csv-file-using-python-and-multithreading for a similar problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289386/loading-multiple-csv-files-of-a-folder-into-one-dataframe maybe this also helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Threading. I took the following code from [here](https://www.shanelynn.ie/using-python-threading-for-multiple-results-queue/) and modified for your use case

```
global times =[]

def my_func(file):
        size=2048
        csvData = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['acol', 'bcol'], header=None, skiprows=range(0,int(size/2)), skipfooter=(int(size/2)-10))

        for index in range(0,10):
            s=s+float(csvData['bcol'][index])
        s=s/10
        averages.append(s)
        time=file.rpartition('\\')[2]
        time=int(re.search(r'\d+', time).group())
        times.append(time)

threads = []
# In this case 'self.files' is a list of files to be read.
for ii in range(self.files):
# We start one thread per file present.
    process = Thread(target=my_func, args=[ii])
    process.start()
    threads.append(process)
# We now pause execution on the main thread by 'joining' all of our started threads.
# This ensures that each has finished processing the urls.
for process in threads:
    process.join()
```