# How to speed up Python CSV Read to MySQL Write

Tags: python, csv

I have a 5GB CSV of IP addresses that I need to parse to a MySQL database.

Currently reading rows from the CSV and inserting into the MySQL. It works great however I would love to make it fast.

Could I parallel the reading and writing somehow? Or perhaps chuck the csv down and spawn from processes to read & write each split csv?

```
import csv
from csv import reader
from csv import writer
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='ips')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
i = 1

with open('iplist.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_reader:
        query = """INSERT INTO ips (ip_start,ip_end,continent) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')""" % (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        print (query)
        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.execute('COMMIT')
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
cnx.close()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950893/processing-huge-csv-file-using-python-and-multithreading and see if it helps you?

Comment: Don't commit after every insert

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar Going to test. Having an issue loading `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: @DarkKnight Implemented that, improved speed slightly. I think I will need to try threading to get the speed increases that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Martin what issue are you facing loading multiprocessing module?

Comment: Insert multiple rows at a time maybe?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar Got that sorted :)

Comment: @Martin. Can you try the solution with `executemany` please?

Comment: How many rows are you inserting and how long does it take

Comment: @DarkKnight 33 million rows. 1% takes 23 seconds. So total time would be around 38 mins I think.

Comment: I have a solution that will insert 33 million rows in around 3 minutes. I'll post it as an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a pseudo-random CSV file where each row is of the style "111.222.333.444,555.666.777.888,A continent". The file contains 33 million rows. The following code was able to insert all rows into a MySQL database table in ~3 minutes:-

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import concurrent.futures
import csv
import itertools

CSVFILE='/Users/Andy/iplist.csv'
CHUNK=10_000


def doBulkInsert(rows):
    with mysql.connector.connect(user='andy', password='monster', host='localhost', database='andy') as connection:
        connection.cursor().executemany(f'INSERT INTO ips (ip_start, ip_end, continent) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', rows)
        connection.commit()


def main():
    _s = time.perf_counter()
    with open(CSVFILE) as csvfile:
        csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile)
        _s = time.perf_counter()
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while (data := list(itertools.islice(csvdata, CHUNK))):
                executor.submit(doBulkInsert, data)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            print(f'Duration = {time.perf_counter()-_s}')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Works well. Just a quick question: does using `with mysql.connector.connect(user='andy', password='monster', host='localhost', database='andy') as connection:` instead of `connection = mysql.connector ....` etc etc improve something? For some reason, using the `with` version doesn't store any data. I change it to a variable and use that connection variable instead and it does, just seems a bit slower?

Comment: *with* is the keyword used with context managers. When the *with* block ends, the relevant class's __exit__ method will be called which will, typically, release all of its resources. If you're having a problem with that code I suspect you copied something wrongly

Comment: Turns out I had an issue with my `mysql-connector` pip package. Reinstalling that fixed my issue.

Comment: Adding another 13 columns of similar sized data has upped my total processing time to 688s for 33m rows. I would assume that sounds about right considering the increase in data?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cursor.executemany` to increase speed:

```
# Tested with:
# docker run --rm -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=y -p 3306:3306 mysql
#
# CREATE DATABASE ips;
# USE ips;
# CREATE TABLE ips (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ip_start VARCHAR(15), ip_end VARCHAR(15), continent VARCHAR(20));

import mysql.connector
import csv
import itertools

CHUNKSIZE = 1000  # Number of lines

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='ips')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

with open('iplist.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    while True:
        records = list(itertools.islice(reader, CHUNKSIZE))
        if not records:
            break
        query = """INSERT INTO ips (ip_start, ip_end, continent) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
        cursor.executemany(query, records)
        cursor.execute('COMMIT')
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Do you have any ideas about the ideal chunk size? Not limited by RAM (64GB).

Comment: Glad to read that. It depends on your `max_allowed_packet` parameter. Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html. Take care, I use chunksize as a number of lines not as a buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be chunk your list. Break it down into `5,000` (or similar) chunks, then iterate through those. This will reduce the amount of queries you are making. Query volume seems to be your biggest bottleneck.

https://medium.com/code-85/two-simple-algorithms-for-chunking-a-list-in-python-dc46bc9cc1a2