# Data insertion not reflecting in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying this post: [How to speed up Python CSV Read to MySQL Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082932/how-to-speed-up-python-csv-read-to-mysql-write) to speed up my data insertion script.
I modified based on my database config. but after running the script, it runs without errors and data not updating in table.
please refer to tick mark code snippet in that post above.
find my code here.

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import concurrent.futures
import csv
import itertools

CSVFILE='C:\\Users\\Downloads\\pattern.csv'
CHUNK=10_000


def doBulkInsert(rows):
    with mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='pass', host='localhost',        database='testdatabase') as connection:
        connection.cursor().executemany(f'INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',rows)
        connection.commit()


def main():
    _s = time.perf_counter()
    with open(CSVFILE) as csvfile:
        csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile)
        _s = time.perf_counter()
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while (data := list(itertools.islice(csvdata, CHUNK))):
                executor.submit(doBulkInsert, data)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            print(f'Duration = {time.perf_counter()-_s}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

can you tell or an updated code why it is not updating.

Comment: Is your intention to add _new_ data to your table, or to _update_ data which already exists there?

Comment: empty the table and insert data from that csv

Comment: The code works for me (using sample data and table).

Comment: @snakecharmerb this code runs without any error but data not updating in my database either. can you tell what might be the issue.

Comment: The most likely cause would be that the csv file is empty, or has already been read;  I'd add a call to `print`  in `doBulkInsert` to verify that threads are actually launched.

Comment: can you share an updated code to try with.

Comment: @Kiran please don't mark python code as an executable js snippet. its not js

Comment: csv file is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you should always do with strings, is to use '' around their names. When there is a space in the name, the query will fail. So instead of :

VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

You could try:

VALUES ('%s', '%s', %s, '%s', %s)

Next issue, the pattern_id should be unique for each and every insert, else mysql will complain and only keep the first. You must be absolutely sure that pattern_id's are unique! If not, create a new column for the key, even when you never use that number.

Also, can you print the Sql statements before you run them. I'm not sure whether your Python code is correct.

Comment: not working throws error if i insert quotes around it.

Comment: I''m sure the single quotes are needed. However, your text may use quotes, do you convert them to 2 single quotes? Example: if your pattern is  McDonald's  then change it to McDonald''s . In Python that is value_to_write = value_name.replace("'", "''"). This uses 2 single quotes, not a double quote!

Comment: Send me the query that throws, I can try it here.

Comment: Single quotes are not needed - the connector package quotes automatically where necessary.

Comment: yes, i feel same as snake comment. my snippet runs without any error but data is not reflecting in my database.

Comment: Is there error logging, for Linux that is: cat /var/log/mysql/error.log