# Python multiprocessing.pool , ThreadPool is not executing function parallely

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read huge csv file and do some actions on it and store result of each processed row in a queue , I wrote code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951257/3025905) answer on SO.

But unfortunately it is not working , any help will be appreciated.

Below is my code.

```
def process_line(drow):
    print('sleeping')
    sleep(10)
    g_descript = drow['desc']
    date_str = g_descript.split('—')
        
    if len(date_str) > 1:
        ndt = search_dates(date_str[0])
    else:
        ndt = None
    drow['ndt'] = ndt
    q.put(drow)




def get_n_line():
    file_path = '/home/ztcUK.csv'
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        cdict = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in cdict:
            yield row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = get_n_line()
    p = Pool(processes=10)

    n = 0 
    for i in f:
        n = n + 1
        print(n)
        p.map(process_line,(i,))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I expect 10 parallel threads running but only 1 is running , I put sleep for debugging purpose.

Below is the output.

[image]

Comment: "_it is not working_" is not a good question or problem description. What is not working? What is the expected output? Have you tried to create a [mre]?

Comment: It is not working as "I expect 10 concurrent threads" but only 1 is running

Comment: How do you conclude that only 1 thread is running? I cannot derive that from what you wrote.

Comment: By the way, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Comment: You are not helping at all.

Comment: What makes you think there is only one thread running at a time? How would you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `pool.map()`. This method sends a bunch of tasks to a pool thread, and **then waits until they're all finished** so it can return all the results as a list.

You're calling `pool.map()` with a single task at a time.  So the `pool.map()` waits until that single task is done before continuing to the next iteration of the for loop

What you want is either to use `pool.map()` correctly:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(process_line, f)
```

so that all of your threads are run as a part of a single map.

Alternatively, keep your current code, but replace `pool.map()` with `pool.apply_async()`.

```
with Pool() as pool:
    for i in f:
        ....
        pool.apply_async(process_line, (i,))
```

As an aside, I highly recommend using `with Pool()...` which ensures that the pool gets closed and joined before continuing.